# Setting dynamic path in the redis.conf using the Environment variable

Tags: configuration, redis, environment-variables

I have a environment variable `MY_HOME` which has a path to a directory `/home/abc`

Now, I have a `redis.conf` file In which I need to set this path like this

```
**redis.conf**

pidfile $MY_HOME/local/var/pids/redis.pid
logfile $MY_HOME/local/var/log/redis.log
dir $MY_HOME/local/var/lib/redis/
```

like we do in command line, so that my config file picks the path based on the Environment variable.

Comment: Looks like there is no support for environment variables in Redis configuration (at least not in 2.6.16), unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Redis can read its config from `stdin`, I do something very similar to what @jolestar suggested.  I put placeholder variables in my `redis.conf` and then replace them using `sed` in my Redis launcher.  For example:

```
==========
$MY_HOME/redis/redis.conf
==========
...
pidfile {DIR}/pids/server{n}.pid
port 123{n}
...
```

Then I have a script to start Redis:

```
==========
runredis.sh
==========
DIR=$MY_HOME/redis
for n in {1..4}; do
    echo "starting redis-server #$n ..."
    sed -e "s/{n}/$n/g" -e "s/{DIR}/$DIR/g" < $DIR/redis.conf | redis-server -
done
```

I've been using this approach forever and it works out well.

Answer (score 0):

i also find a solution,but redis config is no support for env var. 
i think have 2 method:

1. start up redis by a script,script get env var and change redis config.
2. start up redis by command line,and send env var as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

this is not supported by Redis. I recommend you use [`envsubst`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) to substitute in the values of environment variables in redis.conf, on-the-fly, just-in-time, when executing `redis-server`.

example redis.conf:

```
tls-port ${MY_PORT_ENV_VAR}
# this is valid too:
# tls-port $MY_PORT_ENV_VAR
```

example usage of envsubst, when executing redis-server:

```bash
# echo "my env var port is: $MY_PORT_ENV_VAR"
# my env var port is: 8089
envsubst < ~/.redis.conf | redis-server -
```

by default, envsubst will replace all recognized environment variables in the input. however, you can limit this to a specific set of variables. This is done by passing a an argument. For example:

```bash
envsubst '${MY_PORT_ENV_VAR}' < ~/.redis.conf | redis-server -
```

this will only substitute `MY_PORT_ENV_VAR` in the input.

Comment: The idea is inject env vars in runtime , not statically

Comment: I think I see what you mean, writing a redis.conf from a template redis.conf could be seen as static and not dynamic, but if you do not write a new redis.conf to use and instead modify the canonical redis.conf on-the-fly when executing redis-server, as I show in my edited answer, this is as dynamic as it gets, considering Redis doesn't support having environment variables in redis.conf. @alexey-melezhik