# MongoDB Config File (Windows + Environment Variables)

Tags: mongodb

I have just started venturing into MongoDB and the world of NoSQL datatabases. Currently testing a Mongo installation on my Windows. In my config file, I wanted to use Mongo related environment variables that I have set up on my system. But on running the command:

```
$mongod --config $MONGO_HOME\conf\mongod.cfg --install
```

I get:

> Error reading config file: No such file or directory
>   try 'mongod --help' for more information

How can I make Mongo understand and replace the environment variable with the right directory path? Here is what the config file looks like currently:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: $MONGO_HOME\log
storage:
    dbPath: $MONGO_HOME\data\db
```

Comment: try maybe %MONGO_HOME%\log?

Comment: Looks like you cant do that -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002680/is-it-possible-to-add-environment-variables-to-mongodb-config-file But try the It-Z's comment...

Comment: I believe you can't use environment variables in config file. You are also using bash style which will not work on Windows. I'd suggest follow MongoDB documentation at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: I corrected the to the % format @lt-Z. Had the same problem. Currently using the full path but would like to make it possible to easily switch the DB host by transferring the files later on.